# How to annotate a react functional component with both props and states?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am building a react native application. I have a parent component and a child component. The child component has a button whose event handler is in the parent component. At the end of the event handler, I also have to update a particular state in the child component. So for that reason, I made use of `useRef` hook in the parent component to create a reference of the child component. Now, the event handler function looks something like this

```
const handleJoin = async (community: TCommunity) => {
    // ..........
    childComponentRef.current.setIsDataManipulated(true);
    // ..........
};
```

But I am getting a red squiggly line in `setIsDataManipulated` and when I hover over it the following error appears

```
Property 'setIsDataManipulated' does not exist on type 'FC<TChildrenProps>'
```

This must be because typescript has no way of knowing that the child component has the state that I am trying to update. For now, I have only annotated the child component with props types and not state types. I have searched online and found that when using a class-based component, I can pass a second generic type like `React.Component<TProps, TState>` to annotate both props and state. But how may I do so using `React.FC`?

Comment: I'm not sure `childComponentRef.current.setIsDataManipulated(true);` is a good idea. I agree with @T.J. Crowder, you better make it a prop :`don't make it state in the child component, make it a prop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This must be because typescript has no way of knowing that child component has the state that I am tryping to update.

No, it's because the element doesn't have an exposed method/function with that name, for a couple of reasons:

- The ref will be referring to a DOM element.
- But even if it were referring to the child component instance, while that instance may have a `setIsDataManipulated` function in its implementation, but that isn't exposed in any way to the parent component.

This isn't a TypeScript thing (though TypeScript helpfully pointed it out early), the method/function literally doesn't exist on `childComponentRef.current`.

If you want the parent component to control state within the child component, don't make it state in the child component, make it a prop. That's what props are: state controlled by the parent component that they provide to child components. If the child component *also* has to tell the parent that the prop needs to change, have the parent pass it a setter to use.

> I have searched online and found that when using class based component, I can pass a second generic type like `React.Component<TProps, TState>` to annotate both props and state. But how may I do so using `React.FC`?

No, `React.FC` (`React.FunctionComponent`) has only one type parameter, which is for the props. There's no reason for it to have a type parameter for state because it wouldn't be used for anything. With `React.Component`, the state type parameter determines what the `state` property of the component's code instance is, so that code using `this.state` and `this.setState` within the `class` component can be typechecked. But state in function components doesn't work that way. There's no single state object. Instead, you define the type of each state member directly, when using `useState`.

Here's an example: A `class` component with one prop and two state items vs. a function component with the same prop and state items:

```
class ClassExample extends React.Component<{prop1: string}, {state1: number; state2: string | null}> {
    constructor(props: {prop1: string}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            state1: 42,     // If these weren't here, TypeScript
            state2: null,   // would warn they were missing, thanks
                            // to the state type argument
        };
    }
    // ...
}

const FunctionExample: React.FC<{prop1: string}> = ({prop1}) => {
    const [state1, setB] = useState(42); // TypeScript infers `number` for type
    const [state2, setC] = useState<string | null>(null); // Explicit so TypeScript knows it's `string | null`

    // ...
};
```